# How to take good quality screenshots

Tags: images, display, print-screen

I know many ways to take screenshots.

I personally use Galdwin Print screen but when I post the images on any of blogs, the quality doesn't look very good at all.

Check out this image:

[image]

I have used some other software too but none of them gave me the desired result.

Are there any better ways to take good quality screenshots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have saved the image as a JPEG. Save it without compression, or save it as a .PNG file. Gadwin supports this. The compression is the cause of the "ugly" pictures.

Comment: I Guess You are Right. JPEG is actually Compressing my images hence affecting the quality..Let me check it by uploading png n Jpg together.

Comment: I have always thought this says it best - http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/

Comment: @Shinrai: great Link..loved it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7/Vista you can use ["Snipping-Tool"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots) which comes inbuilt in Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Select the window you wish to take the screenshot of.
Press ALT+PrintScreen on your keyboard.
Open Microsoft Paint.
Edit -> Paste -> Save

This method takes a screenshot of the selected window, nothing else. Works on all windowed applications. PNG is an excellent format for screenshots.

If you want to grab a screenshot of a webpage, use a Firefox add-on called FireShot. It's efficient, simple to use, and best of all, free!